# know if a IP belong to a specific subnet and netmask in delphi

Tags: delphi, function, ip, subnet, netmask

I need a function written in Delphi to know if an IP belongs to a certain NETMASK SUBNET.
I have not much knowledge of networking, but I need a function to do this.
I would be very grateful if you can help with this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to check that `(IP and MASK) = PREFIX`.